# Apache Alias to link to another DocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, alias

I have a WordPress installed in `/var/www/wordpress/` and my own code in `/var/www/project/`

Now comes the following problem:
When I try to access `example.com/client/` or `example.com/admin/` it should link to `/var/www/project/` and execute the .htaccess + index.php from there.

I have tried to place an Alias directive in the Apache config with partial success.

```
Alias /admin/ /var/www/project
Alias /client/ /var/www/project
```

When I access `example.com/client/` it works fine, but as soon as I request `example.com/client/login` it failes with `File does not exist: /var/www/project/login` error.

The `.htaccess` in `/var/www/project` looks like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ index.php?module=$1&task=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all: my pet peeve, quoted from from the [manual on .htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) files:

> You should **avoid using .htaccess files completely** if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.

Second: the canonical answer to almost all mod_rewrite questions is [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

I'm not 100% sure, but I think that by setting the [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) to `/` the internal redirect  as you have it will be to example.com/index.php and not to /var/www/project/index.php. Additionally I think the **PT** flag is required to take into account the Alias matching.

You may want to try

```
Alias /admin/ /var/www/project
Alias /client/ /var/www/project
<Directory /var/www/project>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  # Do nothing when a file or directory with the requested name exists
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^.* - [L]

  # Use the request URL to select the correct module and task
  RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$1/index.php?module=$1&task=$2 [PT,L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) shows that this is the expected behavior.  Alias appends any trailing paths after the aliased path.

I think what you want is to throw away the additional path information in the alias, by

```
AliasMatch /(admin|client)/.* /var/www/project
```

That should send the request to /var/www/project, while leaving the URL path of the original request intact for processing by the RewriteRule.